# Root directive in nginx for django/uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, security, uwsgi

Let's say I have a django project in `/home/django/project0/` and my setup is:

```
server {
    ...
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/project0;
    ...

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi/uwsgi_project0.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        ...
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/project0;
        ...
    }

    # similar settings for robots.txt and favicon.ico

}
```

1. Since the static files will be served by different folders and django will be served through uwsgi isn't the root directive useless?
2. What happens if I do not set a value to root?
3. The main reason I am asking is because in many articles online, I've seen people set the root directory to `/home/django/project0`, which as far as I understand makes the project's `settings.py` file public (a practice [not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/security/#additional-security-topics) by the django community). Isn't this approach wrong security-wise or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'd say root is useless here, because it is overridden by location /.

Comment: You realize that this config looks up static in the directory `/usr/share/.../static/static/`?  The Django docs describe very clearly how to change the real location of the static files. Map that directory to the /static/ location using `alias `.

Comment: @Melvyn - Actually I planned to `python manage.py collectstatic` to `STATIC_ROOT = "/usr/share/nginx/www/project0/static/"`, so I properly fixed the syntax above. Thanks for the note and the good suggestion.